# Superposition of sin, cos, tan, arcsin, arccos, arctan taken from 0 to get any positive real number

Tags: real-analysis

You have a broken calculator that computes only functions $\sin$, $\cos$, $\tan$, $\arcsin$, $\arccos$, $\arctan$. Prove that starting from $0$ you can generate any positive real number q. All the functions are being calculated exactly.

Task from an exam that has already finished and I still can't solve it.
My idea was to formulate a simple set of basic functions and prove that through superposing them you can get any $\varphi\in[0,\pi/2)$ then get any positive real number by $tan(\varphi)=x, x\in[0, \infty)$.

I had formulated functions such as $\varphi\stackrel{arcsin(cos)}{\rightarrow}\pi/2-\varphi$ or $0\stackrel{\arctan(cos)}{\rightarrow}\pi/4$.

Comment: Obviously the set of numbers which can be generated is countably infinite, while the set of positive real numbers is uncountably infinite. But maybe the former is dense in the latter, so any positive real number can be _approximated_ by some composition of trig functions.

Comment: You would think that if positive numbers can be generated, the negative numbers can be as well. Also, it's not quite clear what buttons do work on the calculator (digits, period, etc.). Another important point is, do we have a limited number of steps/calculations or infinite?